# Changing datagridview cell color based on condition

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have loaded  the data from database to datagridview and  have two columns target value and volume where volume >target value that volume cell should be in green color and volume < target value then volume should be in red color. I tried it but I am not able to do it.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 && dataGridView1.Columns.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Volume > target value)
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to do this

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dataGridView1.Rows) 
    {            //Here 2 cell is target value and 1 cell is Volume
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Myrow .Cells[2].Value)<Convert.ToInt32(Myrow .Cells[1].Value))// Or your condition 
        {
            Myrow .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        }
        else
        {
            Myrow .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green; 
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile also take a look at [Cell Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't that be incredibly inefficient? Since you are iterating over all records every times any cells are redrawn. 

If you are taking this approach, the entire `foreach ` clause doesn't have to be inside the CellFormatting handler but it should be `dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete`.

Comment: or use var Myrow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex] rather than do a loop

Comment: That is a bad solution, the code iterates all the rows by each cell.

Comment: as @40pro saying it is really slowing down show data very very very much .. with 19,000,00 record

Answer (score 31):

I may suggest **NOT** looping over each rows EACH time CellFormating is called, because it is called everytime A SINGLE ROW need to be refreshed.

```
Private Sub dgv_DisplayData_Vertical_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv_DisplayData_Vertical.CellFormatting
        Try

            If dgv_DisplayData_Vertical.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LevelID").Value.ToString() = "6" Then

                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DimGray
            End If
            If dgv_DisplayData_Vertical.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LevelID").Value.ToString() = "5" Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateGray
            End If
            If dgv_DisplayData_Vertical.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LevelID").Value.ToString() = "4" Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.SlateGray
            End If
            If dgv_DisplayData_Vertical.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LevelID").Value.ToString() = "3" Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            End If
            If dgv_DisplayData_Vertical.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LevelID").Value.ToString() = "0" Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Late comment here: 
This code would be better Dim value As String = gv_DisplayData_Vertical.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LevelID").Value.ToString() Select Value case "1"   e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DimGray Exit Select EndSelect code would be shorter, easier to read and also select case is faster after the third if statement.

Comment: It is changing the color of each cell

Comment: @ken it's faster after the 2nd one but only because he used separate if blocks instead of else if.  An if/else if compiles identically to a switch block.

Answer (score 24):

Kyle's and Simon's answers are gross waste of CPU resources. `CellFormatting` and `CellPainting` events occur far too many times and should not be used for applying styles. Here are two better ways of doing it:

If your DataGridView or at least the columns that decide cell style are read-only, you should change DefaultCellStyle of rows in `RowsAdded` event. This event occurs only once when a new row is added. The condition should be evaluated at that time and `DefaultCellStyle` of the row should be set therein. Note that this event occurs for DataBound situations too.

If your DataGridView or those columns allow editing, you should use `CellEndEdit` or `CommitEdit` events to change `DefaultCellStyle`.

Comment: @dotNET I know post is old - and a very good point. What if you only want to change the individual cell that changed and not the whole row ? And suppose only the binding source is being changed and the cell edit events have not been called ?

Comment: @Ken: You can still use `RowsAdded` event. Instead of using `DefaultCellStyle` of the row, in that case you should use `Style` property of the desired cell. If you need to change style based on data source changes, you should listen to the events raised by the data source itself and change the style therein. For example if you're using a `DataTable` as your data source, you can listen to `RowChanged` or `ColumnChanged` events of the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have to color certain cell (not all cells of the row) by knowing two things:

1. Name or index of the column.
2. Value which is gonna be inside of the cell.

In thas case you have to use event [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)

In my case I use like this

```
private void DgvTrucksMaster_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTrucksMaster.Rows)
     {
       if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Value) > 0)
       {
          row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
       }
       else if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Value) < 0)
       {
          // row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon; // Use it in order to colorize all cells of the row

          row.Cells["Decade1Hours"].Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
       }
     }
}
```

And result you can see here

[image]

So here you can access certain cell of the row in column by its name
row.Cells["Decade1Hours"]

How do you know this name?
Well in my case i create column of DataGridView like this.

```
var Decade1Hours = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
   Name = "Decade1Hours",
   Width = 50,
   DataPropertyName = "Decade1Hours",
   ReadOnly = true,
   DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
       {
        Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
        Font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Bold),
        Format = "n2"
      },
   HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell()
      {
          Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle()
               {
                 Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                 BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
               }
       }
};
Decade1Hours.HeaderText = "Дек.1";
dgvTrucksMaster.Columns.Add(Decade1Hours);
```

And well... you you need for instance colorize some of the cells in the row like ##1 4 5 and 8 you have to use cell index (it starts from 0).

And code will lok like

```
 private void DgvTrucksMaster_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTrucksMaster.Rows)
  {
    if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value) > 0 )
    {
      row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvWebData.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["IssuerName"].Value) != Convert.ToString(row.Cells["SearchTermUsed"].Value))
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

This Perfectly worked for me . even if a row is changed, same event takes care.

Comment: exactly which event would that be?  You didn't list which event this is in.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["balaceAmount"].Value) == 0)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Tis been awhile since I actually posted something on SO, but here we go.

Use _RowsAddedEvent to apply custom style to your grid cells, everything else will just eat too much CPU. And if you're asking this question these days, cpu cycles are important for you.

So, below are the codez to paint you cells depending on the value of underlying databounditem.

```
    private void grid_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        for ( int i = e.RowIndex; i <= e.RowIndex + e.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            var row = grid.Rows[i]; 
            var item = row.DataBoundItem as MovieViewerDataItem;
            if (item == null) continue;

            var cell = row.Cells["FullPath"]; 

            if ( item.FullPath.StartsWith("u:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFF2CC");
            }
            else if( item.FullPath.StartsWith("m:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                cell.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E2EFDA");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without looping it can be achived like below.

```
private void dgEvents_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
    {

        FormatRow(dgEvents.Rows[e.RowIndex]);

    }

private void FormatRow(DataGridViewRow myrow)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(myrow.Cells["LevelDisplayName"].Value) == "Error")
            {
                myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToString(myrow.Cells["LevelDisplayName"].Value) == "Warning")
            {
                myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToString(myrow.Cells["LevelDisplayName"].Value) == "Information")
            {
                myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            onLogs?.Invoke(exception.Message, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dataMain_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataMain.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colStatus")
        {
            if (int.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) == 2)
            {
                dataMain.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                dataMain.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no one mentioned a simple `if` statement can make sure your loop only gets executed once per format (on the first column, of the first row).

```
    private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        // once per format
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                if (row != null)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I found my way here in 2018, so maybe someone else will too.  In my opinion, the OP had a better approach (using dgv_DataBindingComplete event) than any of the answers provided.  At the time of writing, all of the answers are written using paint events or cellformatting events which seems inefficient.

The OP was 99% of the way there, all they had to do was loop through their rows, test the cell value of each row, and set the BackColor, ForeColor, or whatever other property you want to set.

Please excuse the vb.NET syntax, but I think its close enough to C# that it should be clear.

```
Private Sub dgvFinancialResults_DataBindingComplete Handles dgvFinancialResults.DataBindingComplete
            Try
                Logging.TraceIt()
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow in dgvFinancialResults.Rows
                    Dim invoicePricePercentChange = CSng(row.Cells("Invoice Price % Change").Value)
                    Dim netPricePercentChange = CSng(row.Cells("Net Price % Change").Value)
                    Dim tradespendPricePercentChange = CSng(row.Cells("Trade Spend % Change").Value)
                    Dim dnnsiPercentChange = CSng(row.Cells("DNNSI % Change").Value)
                    Dim cogsPercentChange = CSng(row.Cells("COGS % Change").Value)
                    Dim grossProfitPercentChange = CSng(row.Cells("Gross Profit % Change").Value)


                    If invoicePricePercentChange > Single.Epsilon Then
                        row.Cells("Invoice Price % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Else
                        row.Cells("Invoice Price % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If

                    If netPricePercentChange > Single.Epsilon Then
                        row.Cells("Net Price % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Else
                        row.Cells("Net Price % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If

                    If tradespendPricePercentChange > Single.Epsilon Then
                        row.Cells("Trade Spend % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Else
                        row.Cells("Trade Spend % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If

                    If dnnsiPercentChange > Single.Epsilon Then
                        row.Cells("DNNSI % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Else
                        row.Cells("DNNSI % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If

                    If cogsPercentChange > Single.Epsilon Then
                        row.Cells("COGS % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Else
                        row.Cells("COGS % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If

                    If grossProfitPercentChange > Single.Epsilon Then
                        row.Cells("Gross Profit % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Green
                    Else
                        row.Cells("Gross Profit % Change").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                Logging.ErrorHandler(ex)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//After Done Binding DataGridView Data
foreach(DataGridViewRow DGVR in DGV_DETAILED_DEF.Rows)
{
    if(DGVR.Index != -1)
    {
        if(DGVR.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "البدلات")
        {
            CurrRType = "البدلات";
            DataGridViewCellStyle CS = DGVR.DefaultCellStyle;
            CS.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,175,100);
            CS.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0,32,15);

            CS.Font = new Font("Times New Roman",12,FontStyle.Bold);
            CS.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,175,100);
            CS.SelectionForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0,32,15);
            DataGridViewCellStyle LCS = DGVR.Cells[DGVR.Cells.Count - 1].Style;
            LCS.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50,50,50);
            LCS.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(50,50,50);
        }
        else if(DGVR.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "الإستقطاعات")
        {
            CurrRType = "الإستقطاعات";
            DataGridViewCellStyle CS = DGVR.DefaultCellStyle;
            CS.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(175,0,50);
            CS.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(32,0,0);
            CS.Font = new Font("Times New Roman",12,FontStyle.Bold);
            CS.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(175,0,50);
            CS.SelectionForeColor = Color.FromArgb(32,0,0);
            DataGridViewCellStyle LCS = DGVR.Cells[DGVR.Cells.Count - 1].Style;
            LCS.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50,50,50);
            LCS.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(50,50,50);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

make it simple

```
private void dataGridView1_cellformatting(object sender,DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
     var amount = (int)e.Value;

     // return if rowCount = 0
     if (this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
         return;

     if (amount > 0)
         e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green; 
     else
         e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

}
```

take a look [cell formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)