# Changing row color in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

So I am trying to change the color of a `DataGridView` row depending on the value of a cell. Basically, I am dropping real files into the `DataGridView` and it will display the information of that file.

this is what I currently have:

```
double size;

size = Math.Round(MeuFicheiro.Length / 1024d, 4);

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (size >= 0 && size <= 4999)
    {
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    if (size >= 5000)
    {
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else if (size >= 15000)
    {
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
}
```

But this is not working because it does not work because when I insert a new fill it will change the color of all the rows instead of the row I've added.

After making some changes I've got this on the method I've created to display information into the `DataGridView`:

```
private void MostrarDataGridView()
{
    try
    {
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM InfoFile", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "InfoFiel");

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["InfoFile"].DefaultView;

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["InfoFile"];
    System.Data.DataRowView dgrv = (System.Data.DataRowView)
    string fnome = dgrv.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();

    con.Close();
    }
}
```

Do you have any help to give? I just what to change the added row color depending on the value of size.

Comment: Use the [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing datagridview cell color based on condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380279/changing-datagridview-cell-color-based-on-condition)

Comment: Possible but not duplicated @ShengJiang蒋晟

Comment: The line `System.Data.DataRowView dgrv = (System.Data.DataRowView)` looks like its missing something...

Comment: Because I don't know what should I put there @JohnG

Comment: `CurrentRow` does not exist in `DataTable`... @JohnG

Answer (score 0):

To start… Your first sentence and last sentence are contradictory. First you say…

> *So I am trying to change the color of a DataGridView row depending on the value of a cell.*

THEN the last sentence:

> *I just what to change the added row color depending on the value of size.*

Those are two different things, so it is unclear what exactly you want to do.

If you are simply comparing `size`, then ALL the rows will be same color depending on the value of `size`. In your code attempt, if `size` is greater than 15000 then all rows will be orange. But following your code, each row will first get set to red if `tamanho` is less than 5000, then set again to orange. This logic does not look right.

Example: Setting size = 5001 and tamanho to 4999.

```
if (size >= 0 && tamanho <= 4999)
```

In the above if statement it will change the color to red. Then, the next if statement:

```
if (size >= 5000)
```

is executed because there is no “else” clause in the previous if statement. This if statement will obligingly change the color to green because size = 5001. So your last setting of the row to red is unnecessary and confusing.

As long as `size` is less than 5000, all rows will be red if `tamanho` is less than 5000 and white if `tamanho` is greater than 4999.
If `size` is greater than 4999 but less than 15000 then all rows will be green no matter what `tamanho` is.
If `size` is greater than 14999 all rows will be orange no matter what `tamanho` is.

Since the value of `size` (and `tamanho`) never changes while looping thru the rows, your logic will simply change ALL the rows to the color that matches with the unchanging variable `size.` This will set ALL the rows to the same color depending on the value of `size`.

So in reference to you first question: *change the color of a `DataGridView` row depending on the value of a cell.* In your code you are not grabbing any value from any cells in the `DataGridView` to compare to anything. If you want to change a rows color when a particular cells value is greater than a set value, then you need to grab that cells value. Below is one example of how to grab the value from a cell in the `DataGridView` and check its value.

Using your `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)` loop, you can access the FIRST cell/(column) of the current row with the following code.

```
String stringValue = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

If your `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataSet` `Table` then you may/will have to use something different depending on your table. An example is below to get the string from `dgrv`.

```
System.Data.DataRowView dgrv = (System.Data.DataRowView)DataTable.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

The code below will change the row color for that row if the current row’s ‘Cell[colIndex]’ is greater than ‘valueToCompare’. In this case let’s say the cell value is a string but contains an integer value. So to get this integer value and compare it to `valueToCompare` we need to parse the string to an integer then compare the values, then change the row color depending on if the cell value is greater than `valueToCompare`. GetIntValue(string) returns 0 if the string (cell value) is not a valid integer.

```
private void SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(int valueToCompare, int colIndex, Color color)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
  {
    if (row.Cells[colIndex] != null && row.Cells[colIndex].Value != null)
    {
      int cellValue = GetIntValue(row.Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString());
      if (cellValue >= valueToCompare)
      {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color;
      }
      else
      {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // null cell
      row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
  }
}

private int GetIntValue(string inString)
{
  int returnValue = 0;
  if (int.TryParse(inString, out returnValue))
    return returnValue;
  return returnValue;
}
```

Below I used the above method... I set the row color depending on the value of the cell at `colIndex`. If the cell’s value is greater than `valueToCompare` then the row color gets changed to color.

```
// SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(valueToCompare, colIndex, color);
SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(15000, 0, Color.Orange);
SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(5000, 0, Color.Green);
SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(0, 2, Color.Red);
```

This is not the best approach though as an anonymous function/delegate would be one of many better approaches to this problem as this method only compares if the cell value is “greater than” the supplied value, this severely limits the functionality of the method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is always assuming the row with this line of code `SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(0, 2, Color.Red);` and if I insert a size file with 15000 it will not change the row to Orange but I like your idea

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by  _This is always assuming the row with this line of code_? Also the code `SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(0, 2, Color.Red);` has nothing to do with the file size. Its changing the row color based on the values of certain cells. As I said before if the size is over 15000 and you want to change the row colors because of this then do it, all the cells will still be changed. Two different things.

Comment: I will drop a file into my application and it will insert in each column the name, extension, size, etc and I want to create a method that depending on the value of column 'File Size' will change the row color, but only that row.

Comment: As I said in my answer, this may well be the case and I understand what you want to do, however in your code, you are not doing this. `size` NEVER changes in the `foreach` loop and and you never grab any data from a `DataGridView` cell to see if its value is over 15000.

Comment: My code `SetRowColorBasedOnColValue(int valueToCompare, int colIndex, Color color)` does what you are asking. Try it, if the cell you are looking for are valid integers it will work.

Comment: In my code, where is a double needed? The value returned from the DataGridView Cell is a string. At least that's how I was grabbing the value. Your code is comparing integer values with a double, this seems unnecessary for integer comparisons,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129029/discussion-between-johng-and-leugimsnitram).

Comment: DataTable should be the name of YOUR table...
In the chat you posted, but I did not see it. But you need to put the name of YOUR DataTable in this line: `System.Data.DataRowView dgrv =(System.Data.DataRowView)TheNameOFYOURDataTable.row.DataBoundItem;``string fname = dgrv.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();`,

Comment: I do not have any `DataTable` variable, I only got `DataSet`

Comment: A DataSet is a set of Tables... to get your table... Table myTable = DataSetName.TableName.

Comment: I got this: `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["InfoFile"].DefaultView;` the using it to ` DataTable dt = ds.Tables["InfoFicheiro"];` and then what?

Comment: I will actually update the post with what I got at the moment

Comment: If it is, to get the data that is bound to the currently selected row...`System.Data.DataRowView dgrv = (System.Data.DataRowView)YOUR_TABLE_NAME.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;`... then use `string value = dgrv.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();` to get the value in column 0.... etc

Comment: I do I get that "YOUR_TABLE_NAME"? It is from the `DataTable`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129223/discussion-between-johng-and-leugimsnitram).