# How to format dataGrid row color depending on the review date?

Tags: c#, datagridview

**Goal:**

Format the color of the dataGrid rows depending on the following...

- If the review date is 1 month away then highlight red

**Loading dataGrid view**

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
{
    //Creating a data adapter and filling the table with dataSet
    using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT date(review_date) from files", conn))
    {
        using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
        {
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            data.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
            data.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Review Date";    

        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[---Image Output---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGN0T.jpg)

**Question**

How can I format the row color to red, if the date is a month away from current day?

Comment: That does not answer my question - my question is aimed towards date not strings...

Comment: [You loop all the rows **only once** after you bind the datatable and set the row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2193018/3585500) based on the date compare. After that [you only have to format  when RowsAdded or CellEndEdit events occur.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30579757/3585500) For the date comparison [you can probably find the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638993/difference-in-months-between-two-dates)